# HTML - editing code within <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Windows 7 32-bit
Dreamweaver 8

I am new to HTML & Dreamweaver.

I am using Dreamweaver to edit a website originally put together by someone else.

On each website page is some footer code.  I need to edit this code and indeed can do it on every page except one - which is greyed out and i can't edit it?

Is there some way i can edit this code?  I do not really understand why it is greyed out only on this page?  My HTML is very limited and i am currently learning.

The difference between the page i can't edit and the others seems to be the  InstanceEndEditable
and
InstanceEnd
parts

Any advice greatly appreciated

Here is the code i cannot edit...(code preview looks a bit odd hope it's visible - i've had to remove some of the hyperlinks in it as i have less than 10 posts here)

```
   <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
        </div>
<!--$$/content$$-->        
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="Footer">
  <p class="White">Policy</a>| 
  <p class="White"> 
  <div id="simplegallery2" style="text-align:center; width:65px; height:39px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
  <p class="L8_White">...............................................................................................................................................................</p>
  <p><strong>Crystal Clear Development Co., Ltd</strong></p>
  <p><strong>Crystal Clear Vessels Co., Ltd</strong></p>
  <p> 9/115 Moo. 9 , Chaofa Rd., Chalong, Muang, Phuket 83130 Tel/Fax: +66 (0) 76 383 306 Mobile : +66 828 004718, 801 427457</p>
  <p> E-mail: <a href="mailto:  l  Website: 
  <p>Copyright © 2009 Crystal Clear Thailand. All rights reserved. Web design by Alexander Evengroen &amp; 
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"> var gaJsHost =  
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); </script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> try { var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-7136030-27"); pageTracker._trackPageview(); }  
catch(err) {}</script>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: Just indent the code by 4 spaces, or select it and click the `101010` button, to format it as code! Then it's visible here just fine and you should be able to embed as many links in it as you want (since it's code, not links).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't edit code outside of the `<!--InstanceEndEditable-->` sections. You have to modify this from the original template (dwt file). If you want, you can go in a text editor and change it outside of Dreamweaver, but if the DWT file ever gets updated (not a concern if you do not have the DWT file), the footer will be replaced.

The location of the DWT file is often listed at the very beginning of the document. Scroll to the top and you will see a bunch of dreamweaver tags that list information on the template.

Comment: I can see the template at the top of the code but cannot locate it anywhere?

Comment: Whoops keep pressing return by mistake.  I will edit the file outside of dreamweaver as i don't anticipate anyone changing the template wherever it may be?  The footer is the same on every page but strangely he only used the template method on one of them.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, where did you get this from? It would make whatever you are doing much easier if you get the template. However, if you do not have the template, you will have to remove the template link via an external text editor. Once you remove all of the template related text, Dreamweaver will unlock all of the code for you to edit.

Comment: I didn't read your second comment, so you can just ignore the previous comment. That's odd that he didn't use the template code for the other ones. Just remove the template related codes (they appear as comments, such as `<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->`) in an external text editor, and once re-opened in Dreamweaver, all of the code will be editable

Answer (score 3):

I got it guys finally. do this.

Your page is apparently linked to a template.  If you no longer want to use the template, you can use the Dreamweaver command(in the top bar) Modify/Templates/Detach from Template to unlock the page.

got this method from [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Q_23763303.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - looks like you've got to pay to view that page though :(

Answer (score 1):

there is one more solution for that..

1st copy and paste the full code in Notepad..
after that skip    `<!--InstanceEndEditable-->` this part and paste rest of the code in DW..

then you will be able to edit that code..

Answer (score 0):

You can´t edit that code directly because it's a template. You must edit the template in order to edit that area. Look in your Templates folder the corresponding template for this page.

Second way: edit that code outside Dreamweaver, but be aware that any change applied to the template (the .dwt file) will not affect this page anymore.